# Comparing strings in different encodings

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, string-comparison

I have some code that makes requests and compares with expected values. But I have problem comparing the string from the website with the string in the code. My unit test code says:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed.
Expected: <DEVOLUÇÃO DE VALORES>.
Actual:   <DEVOLUÇÃO DE VALORES>.
```

What can I do to compare the values regadless of the character encoding?

Comment: Show us the C# that doing the comparison.

Comment: Since character encoding is a problem for I/O, not string comparison, you should check that you don't have any extra invisible junk characters in your string. I suggest a hex dump to compare them. Alternately, if you're reading the result in a browser, check the source in case one of the strings is htmlencoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to use `Normalize` method:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Normalize(), actual.Normalize());
```

Note taht `Normalize` allows you to provide the normalization form. If you do it, you have to use the same form in both strings.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Turns out the text in the code used Windows line breaks (\r\n) and `Normalize` doesn't account for this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the culture information and do the comparison. Use String.ToUpperInvariant() for the strings and compare it.